# Accessing Visual Studio MEF components/IComponentModel in a remotely controlled Visual Studio instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, integration-testing, envdte, visual-studio-sdk

For an integration test scenario I am trying to start/control a Visual Studio instance remotely and access some of its public MEF components.

Starting and controlling an instance and accessing services via the DTE works fine:

```
var dte = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0", true), true) as DTE;
ServiceProvider sp = new ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)dte);
IVsActivityLog log = sp.GetService(typeof(SVsActivityLog)) as IVsActivityLog;
```

What doesn't work is the standard way of getting the `IComponentModel` which can in turned be used to access the MEF components. `GetService()` returns something but the cast results in `null`:

```
var componentModel = sp.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel)) as IComponentModel
```

Is there another way of getting access to the MEF components or is this scenario not supported?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue when trying to run an extension I wrote for SSMS 17 on SSMS 18. In my solution, `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost` version 14.0.0.0 was referenced and when running it on SSMS 17 everything worked just fine. The line:

```
var componentModel = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
```

returned an instance of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel` from the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.Implementation` version 14.0.0.0 assembly.
When running:

```
componentModel.GetType()
```

in the Immediate Window I would get:

```
{Name = "ComponentModel" FullName = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel"}
    Assembly: {Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.Implementation, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
...
```

But when debugging the same extension (from the same solution referencing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost` version 14.0.0.0) on SSMS 18 the line:

```
var serviceProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
```

returned and instance from a newer assembly.

```
componentModel.GetType()

{Name = "ComponentModel" FullName = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel"}
    Assembly: {Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.Implementation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a}
...
```

And when trying to cast it to `IComponentModel`, the cast would fail.
The solution for me was to reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost` version 15.0.0.0 in the solution since the `IComponentModel` interface comes from that assembly.

Hope it helps